# Lightweight Java Web Services

Tags: web-services, node.js, rest

I was looking a bit at at node.js to use for building REST web services.
It sounds interesting but doesn't support calls to Java well.  I have a Java API for an app that I'd like to be able to use with node.js, but node.js doesn't seem to interface well with Java.
Is there anything like node.js that is more friendly to Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how exactly you want your framework to be like node.js, but I've found that [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) is light-weight and offers good features for that.

Comment: I'm looking into Play! now.  It looks like it may fit my needs.  Thanks!